# Why does aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1 fail without any errors?

Tags: github-actions, devops, pipeline, amazon-ecs, aws-cloud9

`aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1` fails unexpectedly without throwing any errors:

[image: pipeline error]

The GitHub Actions for deploying task definition fails and doesn't give any error to debug information.

Is this the right version of GitHub Actions or I'm missing something here?

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]

name: SupplyX Build

env:
  ECS_SERVICE: **       # set this to your Amazon ECS service name
  ECS_CLUSTER: **       # set this to your Amazon ECS cluster name
  ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: supplyx-ec2-deploy
  CONTAINER_NAME: supplyx-ec2-deploy

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
    
    - name: Automatic Tagging of Releases
      id: increment-git-tag
      run: |
        bash ./build/git_update.sh -v patch

    - name: Build, tag, and push the image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.REPO_NAME }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.increment-git-tag.outputs.git-tag }}
      run: |
        # Build a docker container and push it to ECR 
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        echo "Pushing image to ECR..."
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

    - name: Download task definition
      run: |
        aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition supplyx-ec2-deploy:41 --query taskDefinition > task-definition.json
        echo $(cat task-definition.json | jq 'del(
                  .taskDefinitionArn,
                  .requiresAttributes,
                  .compatibilities,
                  .revision,
                  .status,
                  .registeredAt,
                  .registeredBy
              )') > task-definition.json
        cat task-definition.json

    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: task-definition.json
        container-name: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: updating task-definition file
      run: cat ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Comment: Your workflow seems to be OK.
I suggest manually review, and try to manually deploy rendered task definition - hopefully, you'll see something useful

Comment: Do you see any error on the summary page? `set-output` must be issuing a deprecation warning.

Comment: You may also [enable debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) to find the actual if there's nothing helpful in the summary. As for your question about the correct version, you need to verify that from that action's site to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error issue, it was just because of my `_` in my cluster name; the cluster name actually was `qa_cluster` but I was using it in in github actions as `qa-cluster`.